# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getMicrophones()

Tags: android

I have this very simple which enumerate all micorphone on the device

```
public class MainActivity
      extends AppCompatActivity
{
   private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      AudioManager audioManager =
            (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      List<MicrophoneInfo> mics = null;
      try
      {
         mics = audioManager.getMicrophones();
      }
      catch ( IOException e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      Log.d(TAG,"mics.size() = "+ mics.size());
      for(MicrophoneInfo mic : mics)
      {

      }
   }
}
```

but when I run app on any of my devices, I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.micsrc, PID: 8721
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getMicrophones()Ljava/util/List; 
    in class Landroid/media/AudioManager; or its super classes (declaration 
    of 'android.media.AudioManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at com.example.micsrc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5554)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
```

Comment: Running on API 28 or higher?

Comment: I echo @laalto, the method was added in **API Level 28**.

Comment: @laalto so if the phone api is lower then the app api, the app wont run?

Comment: @the_prole you can check for the phones api in code however if its not at api level 28 the app will crash on reaching that line of code. See the answer from MartinZeitler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to handle that backwards compatible:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    List<MicrophoneInfo> mics = am.getMicrophones();
    ...
} else {
    AudioDeviceInfo[] deviceInfo = am.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS);
    ...
}
```

the "headphone" connector isn't a microphone - but with a duplex headset, it still may have a microphone connected... even if that microphone may not be directly detectable. also BT headsets and even speakers may feature a microphone, which would need to be queried from A2DP sink.